# Which Mongo server to connect to using PHP Mongo?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have 3 replica sets, each in its own shard. Each replica set has 2 Mongo servers (master and slave).

Which server(s) should I connect to when using the connection string for Mongo()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a [sharded environment](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Introduction) you should be running one or more [`mongos`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Introduction#ShardingIntroduction-RoutingProcesses%28mongos%29) servers (typically one per application server) rather than connecting to the replica sets directly.

Excerpt from [the MongoDB documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Introduction#ShardingIntroduction-RoutingProcesses%28mongos%29):

```
The mongos process can be thought of as a routing and coordination process
that makes the various components of the cluster look like a single system.
When receiving client requests, the mongos process routes the request to the
appropriate server(s) and merges any results to be sent back to the client.
```

The [connection](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.connecting.php) to the `mongos` server(s) should be specified the same as you would connect to a `mongod` server, eg:

```
<?php

    $m = new Mongo("mongodb://mymongos1:27017");

?>
```

Comment: Hmm. Thanks Stennie! The docs did not detail how to connect to the mongos using the client.

Comment: @Salocin.TEN: True .. I added a docs suggestion to the Jira issue tracker: [https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-460](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-460).

Comment: I guess it was not added due to some socket exceptions thrown when trying to do certain findOne() calls.

Comment: @Salocin.TEN: `mongos` is what you should be connecting to for a sharded cluster, as it handles the routing of requests to the correct shard(s).  Bypassing `mongos`, on the other hand, is likely to lead to errors because the replica sets don't know how to query across shards.